# DOM addEventListener with transfer parameter

Tags: javascript, events, dom, parameters, addeventlistener

I wrote a program in which a table is created with DOM. When you click on a row (the event is added by addEventListener) of the table a messagebox appears.
This program works so far.

But now I would like to know which row was clicked. 
My idea was a transfer parameter which determines the row. 
But I don't know how to realise that.

If you have suggestions on a better way to accomplish this, I would welcome them.

The program:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init()
            {
                var myTable     = document.getElementById("tabelle_click");
                var mytablebody = document.createElement("tbody");

                for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
                {
                    var mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");

                    mycurrent_row.addEventListener("click", geklickt);

                    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
                    {
                            var mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");

                            mycurrent_cell.setAttribute("id","id" + j);

                            var currenttext = document.createTextNode("z" + j + "s" + i);
                            mycurrent_cell.appendChild(currenttext);
                            mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
                    }

                    mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
                }
                myTable.appendChild(mytablebody);
            }

            function geklickt()
            {
                alert("Es wurde geklickt!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="init()">
        <div id="div_tabelle">
            <table id="tabelle_click" border="solid 1px black">

            </table>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest adding the click event to the Table rather than individual cells. It keep the number of registered events to a minimum and also you can dynamically change the table size without worrying about adding/removing events.  Use event.target || event.srcElement to find out which node was clicked..

Comment: ..also it looks like you're going to be creating cells with the same id - you need to avoid that. I'd use "id"+j+i to keep them unique.

Comment: ..Further to previous post you can find out the row that's clicked either by parsing the cell's id (you're storing the row no. as part of it) or use .parentNode to move up the DOM to the row element